# Eclipse e4 Context Menus

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to build an RCP application with Eclipse 4.2.

First problem; I have a `TreeViewer`. When an item is selected in the tree viewer, I need one of two stacked `MParts` to be displayed. How do I activate a part in a part stack in e4?

Second; I have a context menu associated with one of my parts. I need the menu to appear only when certain composites are right clicked. I have a mouse down handler that is adding an object with all the data I need into the current context (`IEclipseContext`), but I don't know how to access that from a `CoreExpression` (which seems to be the only real way to control the visibility of the menu). The object is removed from the context on mouse up. Say my class is `RightClickData`. How do I write a core expression to test whether an instance of `RightClickData` exists in the current context?

Edit, part of my `Application.e4xmi`:

```
        <children xsi:type="basic:InputPart" xmi:id="_6nSEEJuhEeGpoZf9DvK6pQ" elementId="com.example.MyEditor" contributionURI="bundleclass://MyPlugin/com.example.MyEditor" label="The Editor" tooltip="My Editor">
          <menus xsi:type="menu:PopupMenu" xmi:id="_UdHPEJ4SEeGi0uxvOaa4gw" elementId="MyPlugin.rsmenu" label="Asdf" tooltip="asdf">
            <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_jwOz0J4SEeGi0uxvOaa4gw" label="Add Column" command="_fhTxwJ4REeGi0uxvOaa4gw"/>
            <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_trlpsJ4SEeGi0uxvOaa4gw" label="Delete Column" command="_iAIkoJ4REeGi0uxvOaa4gw"/>
            <children xsi:type="menu:MenuSeparator" xmi:id="_v8f8YJ4SEeGi0uxvOaa4gw"/>
            <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_wR7Z0J4SEeGi0uxvOaa4gw" label="Add Row" command="_bXrp8J4REeGi0uxvOaa4gw"/>
            <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_yf5GMJ4SEeGi0uxvOaa4gw" label="Delete Row" command="_l58HwJ4REeGi0uxvOaa4gw"/>
          </menus>
        </children>
```

Comment: This should be tagged with e4, eclipse-juno, eclipse-e4, eclipse-4.2, or something of that nature.

Comment: For the second question, have you created an `MPopupMenu` for your `MPart` and connected it with your context menu using `EMenuService`?

Comment: I set up a popup menu as a child of my part within `Application.e4xmi`. I then use `EMenuService.registerContextMenu(...)` to connect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can use `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService.activate(MPart)` to activate the part you want.

Comment: This is what I did: `ps.showPart(ps.findPart("my.part.id"), PartState.VISIBLE);`. The `PartState` enumeration also has `ACTIVATE` and `CREATE`. The variable `ps` is an instance of `EPartService` retrieved from the current context. I also had to set the id of the part (for `findPart(String id)`) in `Application.e4xmi`.

Answer (score 0):

I make visible my parts like this:

```
MPart part = partService.findPart("my.part.id");
if( part != null ){
    if( part.isVisible() == false )
        part.setVisible(true);
    partService.showPart( part, PartState.VISIBLE);
}
```